# How do different operators deal with a given string

Tags: linux, bash, string

I want to read two strings as parameters to bash script, these strings are meant to be extensions, then I want to replace the extension of files with the first extension to the second extension.

The best I could think about/find so far is:

```
#!/bin/bash
first=$1
second=$2
for files in *.$1
do
  mv "$files" "${files%.$1}.$2"
done
```

Now, lets assume `$1` is `cpp`, and `$2` is `C`

My "doubts" are:

1. would `.$1` be equal to `.cpp`?
2. Is `*.$1` equal to say: `*.cpp`?
3. Is line 6 equal to `mv "$files" "${files%.cpp}.C"`?
4. Would the previous code handle file names with spaces (like: `my file.cpp`), or dots (like `my.file.cpp`)?

I know I could've said the first 3 question in one question, but I need to understand what is exactly happening, and how will each operator (`.`/`*`/`%`) deal with a given string in a parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two typo's writing `&` instead of `$` for addressing variables, but otherwise it should work.

Also, filenames with spaces will work, since you quoted them correctly.

Minor detail: I'd recommend renaming the variable `$files` to `$file`, since it always contains only a single filename from the list that is looped over.

Comment: I would also add `--` to `mv` (as in `mv -- "$file" ...`) to ensure it can handle file names starting with a `-`.

Comment: @ Joseph R Good point, is there any other options that you recommend to add to 'mv'? or that the way it is written can already handle all kinds of of file names?

Comment: @user2750466 I'm no expert myself but I think this should cover most edge cases.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct with the minor note by [Joseph R.](https://superuser.com/questions/704638/how-do-different-operators-deal-with-a-given-string?newreg=f9cf0a66c854496f945f35e6d8fbb6b3#comment899289_704763) about files containing a dash. However lines 2 and 3 seem redundant, because you don't use the variables `first` and `second` in the snippet.

To alleviate your "doubts" (assuming `$1` is `cpp`, and `$2` is `C`):

1. The `.` is not an operator here, so bash does just a parameter expansion on the `$1`. So the answer is yes, `.$1` is equal to `.cpp`
2. Parameter expansion has precedence over pathname expansion ([link](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06)), meaning `*.$1`  is equal to `*.cpp`
3. Again, the line does what you suppose it does, because first the `$1` is expanded to be handed to the pattern matching algorithm evoked by the `%`
4. The double quotes prevent bash from doing *field splitting*, which is what usually causes problems with filenames containing spaces

Comment: I have a quite stupid question: would the program work correctly also if  $1 and $2 were replaced by first and second, I mean if I did for example:  .first  or  *.first, that would give a similar result, right?

Comment: If you use `$first` and `$second` then yes. The reason is that the variable assignments from `$1` and `$2` no word splitting is performed either.